# Listview template with link

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a listview:

```
<ListView
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="210"
                Height="150"
                SelectedValuePath="SelectedFile"
                SelectionMode="Single" 
                SelectedIndex="0"
                behaviour:CommandsBehaviour.SelectionChanged = "{Binding SelectionFileChange}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding files}"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                atachedProperties:GridViewSort.AutoSort="True"
                atachedProperties:GridViewSort.ShowSortGlyph="True">

                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridView.Columns>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="File Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}"/>
                            </GridView.Columns>

                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

I want when I click the file name (only the file name, not the date) that file to be opened (or any custom action for that matter), i.e the column with the filename to be like a link. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Hyperlink** inside **DataTemplate**

```
  <ListView VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210"   Height="150" SelectedValuePath="SelectedFile"
 SelectionMode="Single"   SelectedIndex="0"   ItemsSource="{Binding files}"     >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>                
                    <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn   Width="Auto" Header="URL" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock  Name="Name" MinWidth="100" Width="Auto">
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path=Name}" Name="NameURl"   RequestNavigate="OpenPageRequestNavigate">
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>  
            </Hyperlink>
         </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                       </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: I get "Event expected" on `<GridView.Columns>` tag

Comment: yes closing tag for Griview.Columns was not there, check the modified answer

Comment: Property "VisualTree" does not support values of type "Hyperlink"

Comment: Please double check, i think you are missing TextBLock